# Neighbor groups based on cluster assignment is slow

Tags: r, performance, igraph

I am doing some analysis using iGraph in R, and I am currently doing a calculation that is very expensive. I need to do it across all of the nodes in my graph, so if someone knows a more efficient way to do it, I would appreciate it.

I start out with a graph, `g`. I first do some community detection on the graph

```
library(igraph)
adj_matrix <- matrix(rbinom(10 * 5, 1, 0.5), ncol = 8000, nrow = 8000)
g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adj_matrix, mode = 'undirected', diag = FALSE)
c <- cluster_louvain(g)
```

Then, I basically assign each cluster to 1 of 2 groups

```
nc <- length(c)
assignments <- rbinom(nc, 1, .5)
```

Now, for each node, I want to find out what percentage of its neighbors are in a given group (as defined by the cluster assignments). I currently do this in the current way:

```
pct_neighbors_1 <- function(g, vertex, c, assignments) { 
  sum(
    ifelse(
      assignments[membership(c)[neighbors(g, vertex)]] == 1, 1, 0)
    )/length(neighbors(g, vertex))
}
```

And then, given that I have a dataframe with each row corresponding to one vertex in the graph, I do this for all vertices with

```
  data$pct_neighbors_1 <- sapply(1:nrow(data), 
                                 pct_neighbors_1, 
                                 graph = g, community = c,
                                 assignments = assignments)
```

Is there somewhere in here that I can make things more efficient? Thanks!

Comment: can you provide sample g http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: still bits missing `Error: could not find function "graph_from_adjacency_matrix"`

Comment: `Error: could not find function "cluster_louvain"`

Comment: Which bit you want to optimise? just focus on that and provide sample for specific transformation

Comment: Those are both function in iGraph. I thought it was pretty obvious you would need to load that library since the question specifically mentions it, but I'll throw the relevant line at the top of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be faster :

```
library(igraph)

# for reproducibility's sake
set.seed(1234)

# create a random 1000 vertices graph
nverts <- 1000
g <- igraph::random.graph.game(nverts,0.1,type='gnp',directed=FALSE)

# clustering
c <- cluster_louvain(g)

# assignments
nc <- length(c)
assignments <- rbinom(nc, 1, .5)

# precalculate if a vertex belongs to the assigned communities
vertsInAssignments <- membership(c) %in% which(assignments==1)

# compute probabilities
probs <- sapply(1:vcount(g),FUN=function(i){
      neigh <- neighbors(g,i)
      sum(vertsInAssignments[neigh]) / length(neigh)
})
```